# How do I sort a possibly-absent array with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, edit, jq

Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "alice": { "items": ["foo", "bar"] },
  "bob": { "items": ["bar", "foo"] },
  "charlie": { "items": ["foo", "bar"] }
}
```

I can sort the `items` array as follows:

```
$ jq < users.json 'map(.items |= sort)'
[
  {
    "items": [
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  }
]
```

However, this crashes if any user doesn't have `items`:

```
{
  "alice": { "items": ["foo", "bar"] },
  "bob": { "items": ["bar", "foo"] },
  "charlie": {}
}
```

Trying to sort it gives an error.

```
$ jq < users.json 'map(.items |= sort)'
jq: error (at <stdin>:5): null (null) cannot be sorted, as it is not an array
```

How can I obtain the following?

```
$ jq < users.json SOMETHING
[
  {
    "items": [
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried using `// []` but I'm not sure how to do this in relation to sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can preserve the original structure if you map the values of the object using `map_values`. Then from there, if you want to preserve the absence of the items array, just check for it beforehand.

```
map_values(if has("items") then .items |= sort else . end)
```

Otherwise if you don't care about adding the empty items:

```
map_values(.items |= (. // [] | sort))
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha, this seems to work:

```
$ jq < users.json 'map(.items |= (. // [])) | map(.items |= sort)'
```