# In jq, why doesn’t `.a |= try sort` work?

Tags: jq

I need a jq filter that would:

- when given `{"a": [3, 1, 2]}`, produce `{"a": [1, 2, 3]}`
- when given `{"b": 0}`, produce `{"b": 0}`

`.a |= sort` doesn’t work in the second case, because “null (null) cannot be sorted, as it is not an array”.

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) I figured `.a |= try sort` should work. When `.a` is an array, it should just `sort` it. When `.a` is null, `try` should catch the error from `sort` and produce nothing, thus deleting `"a"`. This works for `{"b": 0}`, but for `{"a": [3, 1, 2]}` it produces `{}` instead. Why?

I know [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306264/how-do-i-sort-a-possibly-absent-array-with-jq) to accomplish this, but I want to understand why mine doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in JQ 1.6, first reported [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2011) in 2019, and documented [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ/6a7c2d86e603b0eba2ebf55fd47995843adc376e#bugs).

Comment: Please note that the bug was fixed in Nov 2019 and has thus been available in the "development" branch for some time now.